# How to extract question randomly from a txt file containing questions in C?

Tags: c

I have been doing my C project on making a quiz game and i like to ask the users questions randomly one by one from a file containing large no of questions. Can it be done? If not than i will try another method.
So far i have done:

- created a file containing no of questions with answer options.
- created random number using rand() and i am confused how to keep that in array.

Comment: Welcome Arpan. Yes, it can be done. To best receive help, I've found this format of asking questions effective: `1. Here's my problem. 2. Here's my attempted solution. 3. Here's why I'm interested in solving this problem.` You are currently missing #2.

Comment: There's not a good way to directly select a random line from a text file.  You can easily find the size of the file in bytes, and you can easily select a random number in that range.  Somewhat trickier is to seek to that random offset, then find the nearest line beginning or end.  But if you take that approach, you'll end up choosing longer questions more often.  To get around that, you'll need to maintain some external count of the number of questions, and/or an index giving you the offset of the beginning of each question in the file.